# Are there any methods to test whether a data set obeys a certain probability distribution?

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

If one has a set of data, are there any methods or techniques of testing whether that set obeys a candidate distribution?

I have thought of a number of possibilities:

- Simply histogram and look at it, this can already give a lot of clues and potentially create a short list of candidate distributions.
- Bin the data, plot a histogram and then fit the candidate distribution to the bin centres -- look at the residuals or other goodness of fit tests.
- Perform a kernel density estimation, integrate the result and then compare to the integral of a candidate distribution, or some kind of MLE.

My hunch is that there are no "robust" methods of testing a data set if it follows a certain distribution, and of course the number of data points in a data set enters.

---

On the request of a user I am adding some clarification.

First motivation:
From an experimental perspective, data has scatter, looking at the distribution of this scatter can reveal sources of scatter that the experimenter can do something about. For example your data may have Gaussian scatter from fitting, but convolved into it may be a Boltzmann component from some temperature phenomenon.

It is therefore of interest to know "how well" a certain distribution. I.e. is it purely Gaussian, is there an additional component, is it just something that looks Gaussian but isn't at all, for example Poisson with a large $\lambda$ parameter.

The reason I referred to residuals as a possible method, is that if by fitting a candidate distribution, one could compare residuals as a means of testing how well the data matches a certain distribution.

Comment: 1. Re the title: None of those approaches - nor indeed any other - will literally *verify* that a sample came from some specific distribution (rather than some other sufficiently close distribution). It might be better to reframe what you want. 2. You end by talking about *testing*; certainly one can test goodness of fit but that doesn't verify that the data actually came from that distribution, only that the distribution specified in the null is not implausible (in a particular sense). 3. Why do you need to do this; what's it for?

Comment: There are lots of statistical tests, of which the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is probably the most famous. Why do you think tests are not "robust" and what definition of robustness are you refering to?

Comment: Having said, that, most applied statisticians don't care much for testing whether data follows a particular distribution. Real data never follows any theoretical distribution exactly and an exact fit is never required anyway -- one only needs the theoretical model to be good enough to justify the downstream statistical analysis.

Comment: I have added some additional information. Also thanks to @GordonSmyth for the point towards Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

Comment: @GordonSmyth for some context I am an experimental physicist, so underlying distributions really matter and are even useful. For example one can extract temperature information from Boltzmann distributed data.

Comment: OK, I understand. IMO it would be far more powerful to design a bespoke test to detect what you are interested in, e.g. a Boltzmann component, rather than seeking an all-purpose test of goodness of fit, which is what your question seems to be seeking. An all purpose test cannot hope to have the same sensitivity and accuracy as an appropriately designed bespoke test. Also, in order to extract temperature information you need to estimate the Boltzmann component accurately, not just detect some deviation from normality, so you need to fit an alternative model not just test the null hypothesis.

Comment: To take the second example you mention in your question, I don't think it would be appropriate to conduct a statistical test of normality vs Poisson in a physics context. You should be able to decide on fundamental principles. If the physical process can only produce integer counts, then it can't be normal. If the numbers are intrinsically continuous then they can't be Poisson. I think you would always know which is which.